# Adjsutable frame inside a container

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

Is there a way to make the right side's frames (main container) adjustable on y axis?

[image: frames]

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import io
import os

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("640x478")
        self.title("Gil Shwartz GUI Project")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        menu = tk.Frame(self, height=250, width=10, relief="solid")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="flat", height=400, bg="black")

        menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="y", anchor="w")
        container.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x", expand=True)
        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "MainWelcome", "testPing", "PageOne", "UptimeCheck"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = MainWelcome(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = testPing(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = UptimeCheck(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Ping Test", bg="royalblue2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Uptime Check", bg="dark violet",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(4))
        buttun3 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", bg="pale goldenrod",
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(1))
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", bg="gray40",
                            command=lambda: Menu.terminate(self))

        button1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        buttun3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def terminate(self):
        exit()

class MainWelcome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        # img = Image.open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/gil.jpg')
        # self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        # canvas.create_image((0, 0), image=photo, anchor="center")

class testPing(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="skyblue1")
        self.controller = controller

        # self.output = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Output", height=325, width=580, padx=3, pady=3)
        # self.output.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="x")
        # self.output.update()
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self, height=320, width=550, pady=3, padx=3, bg="lightgrey")
        self.textbox.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="y")

        clearFile = tk.BooleanVar()
        clearFile.set(False)
        urlLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Enter URL : ", padx=7, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        urlInputBox = tk.Entry(self)
        urlInputBox.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        fileNameLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Filename: ", bg="skyblue1")
        fileNameInputBox = tk.Entry(self)
        clearFileLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Clear File?", padx=5, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        clearFileRadioYes = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="yes", value=True, var=clearFile, bg="skyblue1",
                                           command=lambda: self.callback(clearFile.get()))
        clearFileRadioNo = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="no", value=False, var=clearFile, bg="skyblue1",
                                          command=lambda: self.callback(clearFile.get()))
        urlSubmitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, height=2,
                                    command=lambda: self.pingURL(urlInputBox.get(),
                                                                 clearFile.get(), fileNameInputBox.get()))
        clearFieldsButton = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Fields", padx=5, pady=5,
                                      command=lambda: self.clear_boxes(urlInputBox, fileNameInputBox))

        urlLabel.pack(anchor="w")
        urlInputBox.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
        fileNameLabel.pack(anchor="w", padx=7, pady=5)
        fileNameInputBox.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
        clearFileLabel.pack(anchor="w")
        clearFileRadioYes.pack(anchor="w")
        clearFileRadioNo.pack(anchor="w")
        urlSubmitButton.pack(anchor="w", pady=1)
        clearFieldsButton.pack(anchor="w")

    @classmethod
    def clear_boxes(self, urlInputBox, fileNameInputBox):
        urlInputBox.delete(0, "end")
        fileNameInputBox.delete(0, "end")

    @classmethod
    def callback(self, clearFile):
        print(f'Clear file = {clearFile}')  # Debugging Mode - check Radio box Var.

    def pingURL(self, host, clearFile, filenameInputBox):

        print(clearFile, filenameInputBox)  # Debugging - Input Validation
        if clearFile is True and filenameInputBox == '':
            self.handler_clr_yes_fn_no(host)
        elif clearFile is False and filenameInputBox == '':
            self.handler_clr_no_fn_no(host)
        elif clearFile is True and filenameInputBox != '':
            self.handler_clr_yes_fn_yes(host, filenameInputBox)
        elif clearFile is False and filenameInputBox != '':
            self.handler_clr_no_fn_yes(host, filenameInputBox)

    def handler_clr_yes_fn_no(self, host):

        startprocs = []
        # nextprocs = []
        lastprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + WriteFile",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_writefile, args=(host,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + PrintOutput",
                          target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_print_output, args=(host,))
        # proc3 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + Generate PrintOutput to GUI",
        #                    target=self.generate_clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui, args=(host,))
        # proc4 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + PrintOutput to GUI",
        #                    target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui, args=(host,))
        proc5 = mp.Process(name="Remove first line + Write new default file",
                           target=self.delete_default_lines)

        startprocs.append(proc1)
        startprocs.append(proc2)
        # startprocs.append(proc3)
        # startprocs.append(proc4)

        # nextprocs.append(proc1)

        lastprocs.append(proc5)

        for s in startprocs:
            s.start()

        for s2 in startprocs:
            s2.join()

        # for n in nextprocs:
        #     n.start()
        #
        # for p in nextprocs:
        #     p.join()

        for l in lastprocs:
            l.start()

    def handler_clr_no_fn_no(self, host):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Append to default file",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_no_writefile, args=(host,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Print Output", target=self.clr_no_fn_no_printoutput, args=(host,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()

        for p in nextprocs:
            p.start()

    def handler_clr_yes_fn_yes(self, host, filenameInputBox):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Clear file + userFilename + Write to file",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_yes_writefile, args=(host, filenameInputBox,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Clear file + user filename + Print output",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_yes_printoutput, args=(host,))
        proc3 = mp.Process(name="Remove Empty Lines from user filename",
                           target=self.delete_userfile_lines, args=(filenameInputBox,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)
        nextprocs.append(proc3)

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()

        for p in procs:
            p.join()

        for np in nextprocs:
            np.start()

    def handler_clr_no_fn_yes(self, host, filenameInputBox):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Keep File + Userfilename + Append to Userfile",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_yes_writefile, args=(host, filenameInputBox,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Keep File + Userfilename + Print Output",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_yes_printoutput, args=(host,))

        proc3 = mp.Process(name="Remove first line + Write new default file",
                           target=self.delete_userfile_lines, args=(filenameInputBox,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)

        nextprocs.append(proc3)

        for p in procs:
            p.start()

        for p2 in procs:
            p2.join()

        for n in nextprocs:
            n.start()


    @classmethod
    def delete_default_lines(cls):

        time.sleep(2)
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default-tmp.txt'
        newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt'

        with open(file, 'r') as inp, open(newfile, 'w+') as out:
            for line in inp:
                if not line.isspace():
                    out.write(line.lstrip())
                    out.write('')
            inp.close()
            out.close()
        os.remove(file)

    @classmethod
    def delete_userfile_lines(cls, filename):

        time.sleep(2)
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}-tmp.txt'
        newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}.txt'

        with open(file, 'r') as inp, open(newfile, 'w+') as out:
            for line in inp:
                if not line.isspace():
                    out.write(line.lstrip())
                    out.write('')
            inp.close()
            out.close()

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_print_output(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", "4", f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def generate_clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        sub.run(f"ping {host}", shell=True, capture_output=True)

    def clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, proc.stdout.decode())

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_writefile(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default-tmp.txt'
        ping = sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE)
        with open(file, 'w+') as output:
            data = output.read()
            for line in ping.stdout.readlines():
                data += str(line.decode())
            ping.stdout.close()
            output.seek(0)
            output.write(data.lstrip())

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_no_printoutput(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_no_writefile(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        with open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt', 'a') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_yes_printoutput(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_yes_writefile(self, host, filename):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}-tmp.txt'
        with open(file, 'w') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_yes_printoutput(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_yes_writefile(self, host, filename):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        with open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}.txt', 'a') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

class UptimeCheck(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Uptime Check", bg="honeydew3", relief="flat")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)



class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", bg="red")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to page 2",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Check [*PanedWindow*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm)

Comment: You also could put a spacer up and/or down to set things how you like.

Comment: spacer? what do u mean?

Comment: Im not sure if you trying just to put the Buttonsin shape or you really want to give the option to adjust them. If you just want to put them in place, even if you change things it should fit to the other stuff next to them, then to keep it simpel use spacer and configure them with your change_my_gui_func(). A Label could be a spacer for exampel.

Comment: i want to be able to adjust them and maybe even put a scroller on the bottom frame.
it's a frame that'll display console output.